# Adding a class(screen) to a class(widget) in kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to make an app in where the top_part of the app there are a Spinner,Label and Button and these 3 are inside a GridLayout with 3 columns. When I click in the spinner. It's displays some choices such as: "Catalogue", "Buy", "Payment Methods".  I want that every time I press the Spinner and select a choice, change the screen that is below of this GridLayout. In these case would be 3 screens because they are 3 choices ("Catalogue", "Buy", "Payment Methods"). and these should be below of BoxLayout in MyLayout(U can see it in the kv.code)

The screens are not working, and I got an error when run the app(invalid class). Just work the part of MyLayout, but from ScreenManager and Screens are not working, I don't know how to fix it.

Py.file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


Builder.load_file('test2.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def spinner_clicked(self,value):
           self.ids.Label1.text= f'You selected: {value}' 



#Definine our different screens
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

This is the kv.file

```
  

<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            

            Spinner:
                id: spinner_id
                text: "Menu"
                values: ["Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"]
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)

        

            Label:
                id: Label1
                text: "My Panel"

            Button:
                text:"Buy"

        Label:
            id: Label2
            text: "My Panel"

WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:      

<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "First Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Next Screen"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                app.root.current= "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left" #up

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Second Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                app.root.current= "first"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
```

Comment: Try to inherit `MyLayout` from some layout class and put the `WindowManager` into it.

Answer (score 0):

As @ApuCoder suggested, you can change `MyLayout` to extend `BoxLayout`, and add the `WindowManager` to that. Just change the definition of `MyLayout`:

```
class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    def spinner_clicked(self,value):
           self.ids.Label1.text= f'You selected: {value}'
```

And modify your `kv` to use the modified `MyLayout`:

```
<MyLayout>
    orientation:"vertical"
    GridLayout:
        cols:3
        
        Spinner:
            id: spinner_id
            text: "Menu"
            values: ["Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"]
            on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)

        Label:
            id: Label1
            text: "My Panel"

        Button:
            text:"Buy"

    # add ScreenManager and Screens
    WindowManager:
        FirstWindow:
        SecondWindow:      

<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: "First Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Next Screen"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current= "second"  # use root.manager instead of app.root
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left" #up

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: "Second Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current= "first"  # use root.manager instead of app.root
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
```

Comment: Thank U, I really appreciate ur explanation, Pls check my answer I have another doubt.

Comment: This is my another doubt. hehe, thanks again: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697095/trying-to-change-between-screens-when-the-screenmanager-is-inside-a-boxlayout-of

Comment: You didn't apply my answer correctly, Change `app.root.current` to `root.manager.current` in your `kv`.