# Trying to change between screens when the ScreenManager is inside a BoxLayout of a Widget in Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I have a problem, when pressing the button "Next screen" , that's not working, and My First Windows is not changing to SecondWindow(Screen)..the app.root.current= 'second' is not working in in the kv.file. And I want to change just the part of the screens(WindowManager:FirstWindow, SecondWindow) and not all MyLayout.. The part of Mylayout  have to stay there and just change the screens that those are below of this.

py.file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


kv= Builder.load_file('test2.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def spinner_clicked(self,value):
           self.ids.Label1.text= f'You selected: {value}' 



#Definine our different screens
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

kv.file

```
<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            rows:3
            

            Spinner:
                id: spinner_id
                text: "Menu"
                values: ["Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"]
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)

        

            Label:
                id: Label1
                text: "My Panel"

            Button:
                text:"Buy"

    
        #THESE SCREENS ARE NOT CHANGING
        WindowManager:
            FirstWindow:
            SecondWindow:  
    
<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "First Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Next Screen"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                app.root.current= "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left" #up

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Second Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                app.root.current= "first"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `app.root.current` references in your `kv` to `root.manager.current` as I suggested in your previous question.

Comment: I saw it! thank U John! It's working now :)

Comment: Hello Sir, again. can U check this? i have another doubt. I'm noob in this.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698873/using-an-spinner-for-changing-several-screensscreenmanager-in-kivy