# Using a Spinner for changing several Screens in kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I need help. I'm making an app, And when i want to use an Spinner. I assigned several values ("Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"). I want that when choosing the value "Buy", My screen change to the "SecondWindow(Screen)".  I was trying to do it from my py.file but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. I was trying to do it from my "def spinner_clicked(self,value):"

If you I can do it from my kv.file straightly. I would like to learn how to do it too.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


kv= Builder.load_file('test2.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    
    def spinner_clicked(self,value):
        sm= ScreenManager()
        screen= Screen(name='second')
        self.ids.Label1.text= f'You selected: {value}'

        #IN THIS PART WHEN PRESSING IN MY SPINNER the choice "buy" I need to change to the SecondWindow(Screen) 
        if self.ids.spinner_id.values == "Buy":
            #self.sm.current= 'second'
            #sm.root.manager.current= "second"
            #sm.switch_to(screen)
            pass            





#Definine our different screens
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

kv.file

```
 

<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            rows:3
            

            Spinner:
                id: spinner_id
                text: "Menu"
                values: ["Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"]
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)
                #on_text: root.manager.current= "second" - it doesnt' work
                #I want to change the screens from here choosing the value "Buy" to the 2ndScreen

        

            Label:
                id: Label1
                text: "My Panel"

            Button:
                text:"Buy"

    

        WindowManager:
            FirstWindow:
            SecondWindow:  
    
<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "First Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Next Screen"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current= "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left" #up

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Second Screen"
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            font_size: 32
            on_release: 
                #app.root.current= "first"
                root.manager.current= "first"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Screen` `names` to the values in your `Spinner`, then you can modify your `kv` slightly. In the `Spinner` section:

```
        Spinner:
            id: spinner_id
            text: "Menu"
            values: ["Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"]
            on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)
            on_text: window_manager.current = self.text  # uses an id defined in the WindowManager section
```

And the `window_manager` id is defined later in the `kv`:

```
    WindowManager:
        id: window_manager
        FirstWindow:
        SecondWindow:
```

The `window_manager.current` refers to the `id` defined for the `WindowManager`, and accesses its `current` property.

Note that the `root.manager` in the `kv` file only works inside a rule for a `Screen`, like inside `<FirstWindow>:` or `<SecondWindow>:`. In that context, the `root` refers to the root widget of the rule (one of those `Screens`), and `manager` then refers to the `ScreenManager` that contains that `Screen`.

Comment: thank you! I appreciate your supporting very much.  The last thing I had to do. It's change the names of the screens  for the values assigned in the Spinner>text, and for linking the Screens from "on_text: window_manager.current = self.text" .  Well, I have one doubt more. What's the difference between ids and names? I saw you can use an "id: window_manager" but i don't know, If I can put a "name: window_manager"

Comment: The `name` property is defined (and required) for the proper  functioning of `Screens` and `ScreenManager`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen.name). The `ids` are entirely different, and are available within a `kv` file (as well as in the python code) to be used to reference the widget with that `id`.

Comment: I got you now. thanks.. Pls John check this new question, I need ur help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731760/create-a-variable-that-contains-an-image-source-from-a-kv-to-py-in-kivy