# Create a variable that contains an image source from a kv to py in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to get the image source and put in a variable from my kv to py. I created a function where my button change the image when pressing and releasing it. Well, this variable has to contains the image source inside my function. I want to use this variable for changing the picture.. I want to create more buttons with the same picture but with different ids, for using the same function many times. I don't want to create several function for every repeated button. Please check my function, def hello_on, the second parameter and in my kv.file check, on_press, and on_release

py.file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Config.set('graphics', 'width', 360)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 640)
kv= Builder.load_file('test2.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
    def spinner_clicked(self,value):
        pass
        #sm= ScreenManager()
        #screen= Screen(name='second')
        #self.ids.Label1.text= f'You selected: {value}'


#Definine our different screens
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    var1= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart.png")
    var2= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart2.png")
    def press_on(self):
    
        #self.ids.my_label.text= "You Pressed the Button"
        self.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= self.var2
    def press_off(self):
        self.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= self.var1
        

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass

class FourthWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

kv.file

```
<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            rows:3
            
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: 65

            Spinner:

                id: spinner_id
                text: "Menu"
                values: ["Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"]
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)
                on_text: window_manager.current = self.text  # uses an id defined in the WindowManager section
                #on_text: root.manager.current= "second" - Just work in Screens

        

            Image:
                source: 'images/ferrepluslogo2.png'
             

            Button:
                text:"Buy"

    

        WindowManager:
            id: window_manager
            FirstWindow:
            SecondWindow:
            ThirdWindow:
            FourthWindow:  
    
<FirstWindow>:
    name: "Catalogue"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        #size: root.width, root.height
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: 180

        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            padding: 4
          

            Label:
                text: "Items"
                #font_size: 25
            Label:
                text: "Number"
            Label:
                text: "Price"
            Label:
                text: "Add to Cart"
            Label:
                text: "tornillos"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                Image:
                    id: my_image
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                    width: 60
                    height: 80
                    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                    source: "images/tornillo.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y+10
            TextInput: 
                id: input_tornillo
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)

            Label:
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping1
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                on_press: root.press_on() 
                on_release: root.press_off()
                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart1
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: root.var1
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
            

            #------------------------
            Label:
                text: "Andamios"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                Image:
                    id: tornillos_image
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                    width: 60
                    height: 80
                    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                    source: "images/Andamios.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
            TextInput: 
                id: input_andamios
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)

            Label:
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping2
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0

                #on_press: root.press_on()
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart2
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: "images/shoppingcart.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
        

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "Buy"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Buy Screen"
            font_size: 32

       

<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "Payment Methods"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Payment Methods Screen"
            font_size: 32


<FourthWindow>:
    name: "Contact"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Contact Screen"
            font_size: 32
```

Comment: Did you try with [`StringProperty`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) ?

Comment: I don't how to use it, can you give me an Example or apply it straightly in this code, please.

Comment: Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I just posted the completed code, check it pls, I'm trying to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

As @ApuCoder mentioned, you can define a `StringProperty` in your `FirstWindow` class:

```
class FirstWindow(Screen, PARAMETER OF MY IMAGE.souRCE!!!):
    variable_of_my_image_source = StringProperty('PARAMETER OF MY IMAGE.souRCE')
```

Then, in your `kv`, you can use that property as the source of an `Image` (as long as the `Image` is in a rule with `<FirstWindow>:` as the root):

```
            Image:
                id: my_image
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                width: 60
                height: 80
                #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                source: root.variable_of_my_image_source
                center_x: self.parent.center_x
                center_y: self.parent.center_y+10
```

Then, you can just change the value of `self.variable_of_my_image_source` in the `FirstWindow` instance, for example:

```
self.variable_of_my_image_source = 'new_image_source`
```

and the `Image` will update automatically.

---

Another approach is to define a `DictProperty` to contain the `Image` sources based on `id`, like this:

```
class FirstWindow(Screen, PARAMETER OF MY IMAGE.souRCE!!!):
    variable_of_my_image_source = DictProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.variable_of_my_image_source['my_image'] = 'one.png'
        self.variable_of_my_image_source['Shoppingcart1'] = 'two.png'
```

Then, in the `kv`, you reference this dictionary for the `Image` source:

```
            Image:
                id: my_image
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                width: 60
                height: 80
                #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                source: root.variable_of_my_image_source['my_image']
                center_x: self.parent.center_x
                center_y: self.parent.center_y+10
```

And you can define a single method in `FirstWindow` to assign to the `Button`, like:

```
def update_image(self, id):
    self.ids[id].source = 'three.png'
```

And reference this method in the `kv`:

```
Button:
    on_release: root.update_image('my_image')
```

Comment: I just updated the code again. When activate the function press_on change to the 2nd picture and release_on return to first picture.. that's ok, It's working in my first "Button with Image". but i wonder if i have to create another function I have to do the same thing with another button. In this part "self.ids.Shoppingcart1.source"  - the id "Shoppingcart1" i will have to change it for example in my second "Button with image", with another id  like "Shoppingcart2" and create another function for changing the pictures in the same way..

Comment: Maybe there is a way to optimize the code & doing all in the inside in the same function, and not create every function for every "Button with Image" .. For that reason I was thinking to create a variable that contains an id since my kv.file to py.file but this is only an idea. I don't know, How?

Comment: See my updated answer for an approach using a `DictProperty`.

Comment: I'm looking for it, But I can't find it. Can you pass me the link?

Comment: Hi @John, can U check this. Pls.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71761617/create-a-recycle-viewgridlayout-inside-a-boxlayout-kivy

Answer (score 0):

I was hanging out to looking for a solution and finally, I found it! I just 2 create 2 variables in a class with StringProperty and write in my kv.file

on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= root.var2
on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= root.var1

for every ids.

py.file

kv.file

```
<FirstWindow>:
    name: "Catalogue"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        #size: root.width, root.height
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: 180

        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            padding: 4
          

            Label:
                text: "Items"
                #font_size: 25
            Label:
                text: "Number"
            Label:
                text: "Price"
            Label:
                text: "Add to Cart"
            Label:
                text: "tornillos"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                Image:
                    id: my_image
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                    width: 60
                    height: 80
                    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                    source: "images/tornillo.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y+10
            TextInput: 
                id: input_tornillo
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)

            Label:
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping1
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on() 
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= root.var1 
                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart1
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: root.var1
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
```